# Auto refresh inner page aspx

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, refresh, reload

I'll try explaining my problem shortly.
I'm a student who is waiting for final exams' grades.
I hate logging in every 10 minutes and go to the right section of the "student's page".

I would like to go there once, and have a refresh every 5 minutes (which is less than the time the server disconnects your account).

Basic browser extensions are built for html web pages.
Our student's page is an .aspx page and therefore refreshing it brings you to the opening page, so you still have to click on the "grades" menu link (which is loaded at the same page, like an inner page).

I want to refresh only the inner page, like if I'm currently looking at the grades page, if I click again on the "grades" menu link then the inner page will be reloaded, but NOT the whole web page.

How can this be done?

I do appreciate that if you guide me through and not just paste me a piece of genius code since I won't know what do with it.

I do thank you guys !

Comment: I know that this can be done using something like [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/), but I'm afraid I don't know a lot about it.  You can download scripts for it, though.  Also, please note that this is not a site where people will just do things for you - you'll have to provide more input than the above.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML META Tag

```
> <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30"> <meta http-equiv="refresh"
> content="30;url=test.aspx">

 Using ASP.NET, C# and MasterPages
    Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", 30 + "; URL=test.aspx");
```

Comment: if you can guide the OP's how this code will work or help him. As he is asking for guidance.

Comment: This looks like the OP only wants a way of continuously updating a particular page on the internet - they're not going to have access to any of the code for the site itself.

Comment: Ashok Dhakhada, How do I use this code?
Where do I put it?

Comment: Paul is right btw, I do not have access to the server. I'm just a client who wants to auto refresh the web sit.e